# Effects of unicorn - visible to me or everyone?

Tags: discussion

There is an option to adopt a tag. Nice joke, all right, but I wonder if we can see what each other buy? Or is it a kind of playing with yourself? :D

Comment: The animated unicorns when voting are great, a real pick me up in the morning. Thoroughly recommend it :) (I can't imagine that this is anything other than client-side and per-user only, by the way, though wouldn't it be great if it wasn't?)

Comment: @Clive So all the tags I adopted, hugged and cared for... for NOTHING?!

Comment: Well, not for nothing...think of all the unicorns who can now have a better life thanks to your sponsorship

Comment: @Clive but they won't let me pay in bacon :(

Comment: nice april fool!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened up some of my Unicoin-purchase adorned pages in another browser were I was not logged in, and none where visible.  No 10x reputation attached to my profile, no missing downvote buttons, no sponsored tags, no "helpful" instant answers, etc.

But it is a good April's fool day joke and the voting animation is kind of cute!

Too bad about the pluralization bug `:-(`.

[image]